# Assigning values in VHDL

Tags: bit-manipulation, vhdl, ieee-754

I am stuck in a problem.
I have like this type of binary code. (actually I have data in 10 rows, but here I am showing 3 rows only).

1000011100101000001111

1110000111101010000111

1000000000011110000010

and now i want to assign each row to output 1, output 2, output 3 (let's say).

Basically, I am reading this type of data from a text file and I want to assign each row to array type variable.

how could we do that in VHDL. Any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
entity e is
port( output1 : out std_logic_vector(22 downto 0));
end entity

architecture rtl of e is
begin
  output1 <= "1000011100101000001111";
end architecture;
```

is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a std_logic_textio package or something similar.

http://www.vhdl.org/rassp/vhdl/models/standards/std_logic_textio.vhd

A good example is shown here on how to do this:

http://www.stefanvhdl.com/vhdl/html/file_read.html